# XPath attribute query and retrieve

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I've been having some trouble getting my head around XPath.

Want i want to do, is to extract an exchange rate from a currency country code.

My XML with currecies is here: http://www.nationalbanken.dk/dndk/valuta.nsf/valuta.xml

This is my query:

```
query = xml.XPathSelectElement(**"exhangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code='"+ country +"']@rate"**).Value;
```

I'm workiing in .NET 3.5 and a asp webservice project, which produces the following error:

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'exhangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code='USD']@rate' has an invalid token.
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseXPathExpresion(String xpathExpresion)
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.QueryBuilder.Build(String query, Boolean allowVar, Boolean allowKey)
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.QueryBuilder.Build(String query, Boolean& needContext)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(String xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate(String xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator.Evaluate[T](XNode node, String expression, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
   at System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElements(XNode node, String expression, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
   at System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement(XNode node, String expression)
   at WebServiceCurrency.Service1.RetrieveExchangeRate(String country) in c:\Users\Peter\Documents\GitHub\HotMess\C#\Webservices\WebServiceCurrency\WebServiceCurrency\Service1.asmx.cs:line 35
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that i want the rate attribute, on the condition of country code. I've been unable to find examples with several attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
 <xsl:template match="/">

   <xsl:value-of select="//dailyrates/currency[@code='USD']/@rate" />

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
566,97
```

So the solution for you should be

```
query = xml.XPathSelectElement(**"exhangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code='"+ country +"']/@rate"**).Value;
```

Comment: result = float.Parse(xml.SelectSingleNode("//dailyrates/currency[@code='" + countryCode + "']/@rate").Value);

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is trying to tell you that your XPath has a syntax error.  For

```
"exhangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code='"+ country +"']@rate"
```

read

```
"exhangerates/dailyrates/currency[@code='"+ country +"']/@rate"
```

That is, insert a slash between the step in which you navigate to the `currency` node and the following step in which you navigate to its `rate` attribute.  (I see that PCM beat me to this solution. Hats off.)

Comment: I've used PCM's expression, but is still getting this error :                           System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute.

   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator.<EvaluateIterator>d__0`1.MoveNext()

Comment: You're calling a method whose [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelement.aspx) says it selects and returns an element, and handing it an XPath expression that selects an attribute.  Try looking for another method?  (Perhaps XPathEvaluate will do what you need?  Perhaps first select the currency element using XPathSelectElement, then evaluate the expression "./@rate" using that element as the context node in a call to XPathEvaluate?).  In any case, read error messages as if they were trying to tell you something.  They are.

Comment: Ok? Why plaster good advise, with condescending bullshit? I commented a working one-liner. No points for you mate.

Comment: Sorry to have offended you; no condescension intended.  Twice now you have asked how to solve a problem when the error message you report makes the nature of the problem clear and an obvious solution follows from the nature of the problem.  It looks to me as if you're not looking carefully at the error messages; if you want help from others, you want to look as if you're putting in some effort.